# setTimeout inside Promise Race immediately catch

Tags: javascript, timer, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

I have 2 promise, a `fetch` and a `setTimeout`, fetch wait for 5 seconds and setTimeout wait 4 seconds.

I don't known why but setTimeout fire immediately!

```
myService( args )
    .then( result => {
        console.log(result);
    })  
    .catch( timeoutError => {  // <-----------------  FIRE IMMEDIATELY
        console.error(timeoutError);
    })
;


function myService( args ){
    return Promise.race([
        fetch("http://localhost/wait-ten-seconds"),
        new Promise( (_, timeexpired) => {
            return setTimeout( function() {
                console.log("timeout");
                timeexpired({msg: "call timeout", code: 100, data: null});
            }
            , 4000)
        })
    ]);
}
```

Comment: *fetch wait for 5 seconds* Don't see this anywhere... looks like a CORS issue

Comment: @CertainPerformance it's the first element of the `Promise.race()` array argument

Comment: @PatrickEvans Oh, is that what the `delay/5000/` part of the URL does, it's not just a random path

Comment: `fetch("http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/5000/url/http://www.google.co.uk")` make a `GET` call, wait for 5 seconds and then response

Comment: What is the error `console.error(timeoutError)` ?

Comment: fetch rejects immediately with `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/5000/url/http://www.google.co.uk. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: the fetch is failing regardless of how you do it, it can never succeed because the server doesn't allow CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it in this way:
I create a function that simulate timeout

```
let activeTimer = null;
let checkTimer = (startTimer, timeExpired) => {
    activeTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        if( (new Date()).getTime() - startTimer < TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS ) checkTimer(startTimer, timeExpired);
        else timeExpired( errorMessage.TIMEOUT_EXPIRED );
    }, 1000);
};

Promise.race([
    new Promise( (httpResponse, httpError) => {
        return fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                clearTimeout( activeTimer );
                activeTimer = null;
                httpResponse( response );
            })
            .catch( error => {
                httpError( error );
            })
        })
        ,
        new Promise( (_, timeExpired) => {
            checkTimer((new Date()).getTime(), timeExpired);
        })
]);
```